# Mvvmcross MvxListView item access viewmodel

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a viewmodel with a list of a custom class. This list is displayed in my ui using a MvxListView. I can easly access the properties of the customs class, but what I need right now is a way to acces the viewmodel from them item template **without** modifying the class:

The class:

```
public class MyDataClass
{
    public string Name {get; set;};
}
```

The viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    //...
    private string _sample;
    public string Sample
    { 
        get { return this._sample; }
        private set { this.SetProperty(ref this._sample, value); }
    }

    private List<MyDataClass> _dataList;
    public List<MyDataClass> DataList
    { 
        get { return this._dataList; }
        private set { this.SetProperty(ref this._dataList, value); }
    } 
}
```

The MvxListView inside the view View:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/testListView"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource DataList"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/data_item" />
```

And finally, the `data_item`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    local:MvxBind="Text Name + ???.Sample"
    android:textColor="@color/primary"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp" />
```

The thing I need to get is `???.Sample`, which should be the MyViewModel.Sample - but I don't know how to get it!

*Note:* I can not modify the MyDataClass to add the ViewModel as a property, this one has to stay unchanged. The Viewmodel itself and the views can be modified without a problem, to solve this.

Comment: Can you modify the MyViewModel class?

Comment: Yes I can, it's just the MyDataClass that must stay unchanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a new class which wraps the `MyDataClass` class and add the new property which returns the concatenated property that the view needs. In the `Sample` setter loop over the list and update the new property.

Comment: I was afraid it would come to this. To bad, that there is no way to access the parent. (It seems that was a feature that was planned, but never implemented...)